# Running Java app from inside emacs using JDEE throws NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, emacs, jde

I have configured JDEE in emacs. But when I try to run any App, it throws NoClassDefFoundError . 
Upon compilation, although a class file is created, it only shows the buffer for sometime and then closes it.

The same files if compiled and run from the terminal work perfectly fine.

Also, on this machine I have java-6-openjdk installed. I had configured JDEE on my home computer which has sun java jdk and there are no such problems there.

Other than this, features such as code completion, generation etc work fine.

How do I solve this? Is this due to open jdk ?

I am using a Ubuntu 10.04 desktop.

This is the stack trace

```
cd /home/vineet/java/KodeJava/src/org/kodeplay/kodejava/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java org.kodeplay.kodejava.EmacsTest

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kodeplay/kodejava/EmacsTest
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kodeplay.kodejava.EmacsTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: org.kodeplay.kodejava.EmacsTest. Program will exit.

Process org.kodeplay.kodejava.EmacsTest exited abnormally with code 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the whole stacktrace please?

Comment: edited the question with the the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something in your config is wrong.  you are trying to run from the "/home/vineet/java/KodeJava/src/org/kodeplay/kodejava/" directory, but in order to find your class on the classpath, you should be running from "/home/vineet/java/KodeJava/src/".  Probably need to configure the "jde-run-working-directory" variable.

Comment: Yes, it works now after configuring jde-run-working-directory. But it seems that every time I switch between projects it will have to be re-configured. Is there a way to avoid this ? I don't remember doing anything like this on my home computer. Will check again anyway after getting back home. Thanks a ton!

Comment: you can setup the jde project support so that it sets those variables appropriately depending on which project a file is associated with.

Answer (score 0):

From the question, it sounds as if the JDEE configuration is not complete when it comes to setting up the command to be launched when running the Java App.

If the same Java App can be run from the terminal with no issues, OpenJDK is not causing the trouble, I'd wager.

Perhaps you copied over from the other computer the JDEE configurations and did not adopt them for the new computer that has OpenJDK.